# Django Test client.get() returns 302 code instead of 200

Tags: django, django-urls, django-tests

Running a test on a url returns 302 instead of 200. Yet testing the same urls in production with a redirect tester returns 200. Not really sure what's going on.

tests.py

```
def test_detail(self):
    response = self.client.get('/p/myproduct-detail.html')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^p/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+).html$', main.views.product_detail, 
        name='product-detail'),
```

views.py

```
def product_detail(request, slug):
    stuff...
    return render(request, 'product-detail.html', {})
```

If I add `follow=True` to `client.get()` I receive 200 code as expected.

Comment: When you open the url with your browser, the final url that opens is /p/myproduct-detail.html or /p/myproduct-detail.html/ ?

Comment: @Kostas /p/myproduct-detail.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Print the value of `response['location']` in your test before your `assertEqual` line. It will show you where the client is being redirected to (e.g. the login page).

```
def test_detail(self):
    response = self.client.get('/p/myproduct-detail.html')
    print(response['location'])
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: thanks, returns "/". Ah I think I've figured it out thanks to this, it must be raising a Http404() and redirecting to the index. This is my first time creating tests, I assumed it used a copy of the dev db but I now see this isn't the case!

Comment: The test database that Django creates is not a copy of your dev db. You may have to create some objects in your test database before you run your tests, for example using [`setupTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this! I am using DjangoCMS and it prepended a '/de/' (so, my language prefix) before my actual URL. Took me hours to find this issue! -.-